# Bullet hits the object not in the center of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When player shoot, the bullet fly to the center of the screen. But if player stay too close to some object, then bullet hits it not in the center, because it flies from the gun on the right side of the screen. How can I fix this?

```
 public Rigidbody projectile;
 public int speed = 50;
 public Transform startBulletPosition;

 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
     {
         Rigidbody clone;
         clone = Instantiate(projectile, startBulletPosition.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
         var centre = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0f);
         var ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(centre);
         clone.velocity = ray.direction * speed;
     }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Because you are not spawning your bullet in the centre, you could try **Raycast** to see if any object is front of you. If so get the distance between **BulletSpawn** point and the **object in front** . Calculate the angle for bullet to hit centre. Use it in your **transform**

Comment: Have you been to an actual shooting range before? I'd totally expect that behavior if I was forced to hold my gun like that (or if it is mounted excentric on something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Rigidbody projectile;
public Transform startBulletPosition;
public float speed;
public float rotationSpeed;
public Camera camera;

Vector3 startingDirection;

void Start() {

    startingDirection = startBulletPosition.transform.forward;

}

void Update() {

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {

        RaycastHit hit;
        Vector3 targetDirection;

        if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, camera.transform.forward, out hit)){

            targetDirection = hit.transform.position - startBulletPosition.position;

        } else {

            targetDirection = startingDirection;
        }

        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards( startBulletPosition.transform.forward, targetDirection, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f);
        startBulletPosition.transform.forward = newDirection;

        Rigidbody clone;
        clone = Instantiate(projectile, startBulletPosition.position, startBulletPosition.rotation) as Rigidbody;
        clone.velocity = targetDirection * speed;

    }

}
```

I would do a Raycast from the Camera Position to see what you can hit and then rotate the weapon to that direction. As in my Example Code. The weapon will point to exactly Center View on what your camera Raycast hits.

Also you can control the max turnspeed by that public float. This will make for a nice weapon movement and not just instantaneous jumps.

Here are the docu links of what I used in this snippet:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.RotateTowards.html

If the raycast misses, the stored original direction of the weapon will be used. (Assuming startBulletPosition is the transform of the weapon...)

If you want, you can add the maxDistance Parameter to the Physics.Raycast call to limit the distance on which this behaviour is active.